# Why am I not able to accept merge request in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, merge-request

I create a merge request for an other user, which I also control in GitLab. Unfortunatelly no `ACCEPT` button appear on Merge Request page for the other user. Other user is also Maintainer. I see many progress bar running. Why? I cheked Merge Request is not a premium service with GitLab. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

[image]